# How do you read multiple specific datasets and append to one big dataset?

Tags: sas, sas-macro

How do you read multiple specific datasets and append to one big dataset?

For example I within a library I have 100s of datasets but I only want to append the datasets that have _du1, _du2

The format and column names are the same

My stab of it doesnt work:

```
PROC SQL NOPRINT;
SELECT memname INTO :tab1-:tab103 FROM sashelp.vtable
where memname like '_DU%';
SELECT count(*) INTO :obs FROM sashelp.vtable
where memname like '_DU%';
QUIT;

%macro rubber;
%do i=1 %to i=&obs;
proc append base=tot_comb data=&&tab&i force;
run;
%end;
%mend;

%rubber;
```

Comment: only data sets that start with _du ?

Comment: Yes only _du datasets

Comment: I've answered it. I added an extra equals in the do loop.

Answer (score 5):

PROC APPEND may not actually be faster in this case, or at least not faster by enough to justify doing it, than just writing a datastep.

```
data tot_comb;
set work._DU:; *or your libname;
run;
```

This will work if you are on SAS 9.2 or later.  If you're on 9.1 or earlier, you'll need to do one proc sql step, like

```
proc sql;
select memname into :namelist separated by ' '
  from dictionary.columns
  where libname='WORK' /* or your libname */
  and memname eqt '_DU';
quit;
*eqt is like starts with;
data tot_comb;
set &namelist;
run;
```

That only requires one pass to write, and I'm not sure it will be much slower than so many calls to PROC APPEND.

Answer (score 1):

Here is some code that will get you all the data set names from a given library with some characteristics (starts with _DU). You could use the final macro in a variety of ways to append data sets.

```
Data _DU1;
 var="One";
Run;
Data _DU2;
 var="Two";
Run;

PROC SQL;
 create table main as
 SELECT *
 FROM DICTIONARY.COLUMNS
 WHERE UPCASE(LIBNAME)="WORK" AND
 UPCASE(MEMNAME) like '_DU%';

 Select memname
 into :dsn separated by ' '
 from main;
QUIT;

%Put &dsn;
```

**EDIT (according to your comment)**

I added some UPCASE statements and used your count macro var for the number of tab macros
Narrowing your where statement should make your code more efficient

Try this (some of the code is untested):

```
 PROC SQL NOPRINT; 
  SELECT count(*) 
  INTO :obs 
  FROM sashelp.vtable 
  where UPCASE(LIBNAME)="<YOUR LIB IN UPCASE>" AND
        upcase(memname) like '_DU%'; 
 %Let obs=&obs;
  SELECT memname 
  INTO :tab1-:tab&obs 
  FROM sashelp.vtable 
  where UPCASE(LIBNAME)="<YOUR LIB IN UPCASE>" AND
       upcase(memname) like '_DU%'; 

 QUIT; 

 %macro rubber; 
  %do i=1 %to &obs; 
   proc append base=tot_comb data=&&tab&i force; run; 
  %end; 
 %mend; 
 %rubber;
```

Comment: PROC SQL NOPRINT;
SELECT memname INTO :tab1-:tab103 FROM sashelp.vtable
where memname like '_DU%';
SELECT count(*) INTO :obs FROM sashelp.vtable
where memname like '_DU%';
QUIT;

%macro rubber;
%do i=1 %to i=&obs;
proc append base=tot_comb data=&&tab&i force;
run;
%end;
%mend;

%rubber;

Comment: Ive done above but its not working :( sorry better view of it:

Comment: if the above doesn't work, let me know the errors and I will try to fix it